# Pick out part of text field in Python with Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, date, web-scraping, scrapy

Built a web scraper with Scrapy. Here's what I want to extract:

```
Friday March 14, 2014
```

When I grab what's in this div (it's not in paragraph tags or anything I can get more specific with) using this:

```
item['published'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
```

And here's what I get:

```
\n    \n        Last Updated: Friday, March 14, 2014 \n        ", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "\n", "            \n
```

So how do I ditch the everything before Friday and after 2014 in this example? I spent hours playing with some regular expressions but for the life of me can't seem to find a good example of how to do this when dealing with letters and not numbers, or worse, something that doesn't deal with exact spaces and ranges because sometimes it says "Last Updated:" and sometimes it says "Updated:" and that leaves me in a seemingly unusual spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the date from the string, example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '\n    \n        Last Updated: Friday, March 14, 2014 \n        ", "\n '
>>> re.search('Updated: ([\w, ]+)', s).group(1).strip()
'Friday, March 14, 2014'
```

Where `([\w, ]+)` is a saving group that matches 1 or more alphanumeric characters (and `_` too), comma or space.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I may be doing this incorrectly, because I'm getting this error:

re.search('Updated: ([\w, ]+)', s).group(0).strip()
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
 exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer

Here's what I'm trying to do in the spider:

        firstDate = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
        s = firstDate
        re.search('Updated: ([\w, ]+)', s).group(0).strip()
        item['published'] = s
        return item

Comment: @Chris, probably you get a list from the `extract()` call. Check what is the type of `firstDate` and if it's a list take the first item from it: `firstDate = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()[0]`.

Comment: You can also use `.re()` method with `SelectorList`: `item['published'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').re(r"Updated: ([\w, ]+)")`

Comment: @pault, That worked for me. My final question on this is how to adjust that expression to include am/pm as some of these dates include that at the end. It's now grabbing something like "March 15, 2014 5" and leaving off a final ":15 pm" I'd like to include. Thanks so much for the help because I'd been stuck on this a couple days.

Comment: @Chris, just allow `:` char too: `item['published'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').re(r"Updated: ([\w, :]+)")`.

Comment: @alecxe, That worked like a charm and seeing it in action sheds some light on how regex is working there. Thank you so much!